# Several fields and GEOMETRY GetFeatueInfo from GeoServer

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wms, geometry, getfeatureinfo

I have a table in PostGIS 2.0 with several fields of type GEOMETRY.

In the geometry_columns they are published in GeoServer 2.2 as layers. This is done as here - [GeoServer docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-tipstricks/mixed-geometries.html), but immediately after the GetFeatueInfo stopped working in these layers.

Does anyone know whether you can configure the server to serve multiple fields of geometry.

Comment: Are these multiple geometries per DB row, i.e. something like a multi-point where each point is in its own geometry column?

Comment: 3 geometry column: MultiPoint, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon.

Comment: Each field can be NULL.

Comment: Your link isn't working. Can you update it please?

Do you need to have all the geometry types in one layer? You could keep them in the same table, but use a view in GeoServer to split them out.